# SwiftUI Slider's label visibility

Tags: swiftui, slider

Under what circumstances `SwiftUI` `Slider`'s label is visible?
`Slider` inits can take label arguments, but I don't understand what this label is for?

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var slVal: CGFloat = -20
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $slVal, in: -40...40, minimumValueLabel: Text("-40"), maximumValueLabel: Text("40")) {
            Text("Invisible text") // This view is not visible 
        }
        .padding()
    }
 }
```

Putting `Slider` inside `Form` doesn't make label appear. I know that `DatePicker`'s label is displayed or not depending on `.labelsHidden()` modifier and also on `DatePickerStyle` applied by `.datePickerStyle()` modifier.
Is there something similar with `Slider`?

Answer (score 8):

It is long known bug in SwiftUI.

Here is possible workaround. Prepared with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1 (backward compatible with SwiftUI 1.0)

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var slVal: CGFloat = -20
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Invisible text")
            Slider(value: $slVal, in: -40...40, minimumValueLabel: Text("-40"), maximumValueLabel: Text("40")) {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks more like an undone thing rather than a bold bug.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified version of workaround from @Asperi:

```
func slider<V, C>(
    value: Binding<V>,
    in bounds: ClosedRange<V> = 0...1,
    label: () -> C,
    onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }
) -> some View where V : BinaryFloatingPoint,
                     V.Stride : BinaryFloatingPoint,
                     C: View {
    HStack {
        label()
        Slider(
            value: value,
            in: bounds,
            onEditingChanged: onEditingChanged,
            label: { EmptyView() }
        )
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
slider(value: $aValue, in: -1...1, label: {
    Text("aValue")
})
```

Comment: It can be handy, but I hope they will just fix label at some point of future along with giving some styles to sliders as it is done for `Buttons`, `Pickers`, `Text Fields`, `Toggles` and so on.
Maybe a convenience init (not a free function) would be more appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation not all slider styles show the labels, but even in those cases, SwiftUI uses the label for accessibility (for example VoiceOver).

Comment: I wonder what slider styles display labels? I tried to create a macOS toolbar with a slider, and its label is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Slider does not seem to show label in compact size class. I usually make an extension like this

```swift
extension Slider {
    func inLabeled(label: Text) -> some View {
#if os(OSX)
        self
#else
        LabeledContent {
            self
        } label: {
            label
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

then apply it to Slider

```swift
Slider(value: $speechManager.rate, in: min ... max) {
    Text("Rate")
}
.inLabeled(label: Text("Rate"))
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Won't it be labeled twice for regular size classes this way? On iPads for example. We kind of duplicating labels here, don't we?

Comment: Ja, you can tweak this to your need, just an idea